# How can I pass a variable to a stringified function without using globals?

Tags: javascript

I have a script which was downloaded via XHR. I want to pass a piece of data to this script without adding anything to the global scope. I.e. I dont want to make the function that the script has a global and I dont want to make the parameters which I want to pass to the function global.

To be more clear, I would like to accomplish the following without the use of eval:

```
(function(){
    var myToken = '1234';
    $.get(url).then(function(script){
        // script could be something like: '(function(z){ console.log(z);     })'
        var a = eval(script);
        a(myToken);
    });
})();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with `eval`? And after all, you say you have a "stringified function", so you *need* some form of `eval`.

Comment: i wanted to keep the scope of the evaluated code separate from the calling code.

Comment: `var a = eval(script)` *is* in the global scope, since it's inside an anonymous callback. What exactly are you trying to achieve? You say you need a certain behavior, but you don't say why.

Comment: @JoshBeam the goal is proper code isolation, I dont want code from the script to have access to any variable that I dont explicitly pass it that is inside of the IIFE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *indirect* `eval` call evaluates the code in global scope, e.g.

```
var a = (0,eval)(script);
```

[`"use strict";` might also be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10489874/218196)