# JavaScript eval for expressions in somewhat isolated environment

Tags: javascript, eval, sandbox

I have an array of instructions that look like this:

```
[
  {"name": "a", "expr": "1"},
  {"name": "b", "expr": "4"},
  {"name": "c", "expr": "a * b + 100"},
  {"name": "a", "expr": "a - 5"}
]
```

I want to execute them using a JavaScript engine running in a browser and access the results afterwards.

Obviously, try first try was just

```
eval(inst.name + " = " + inst.expr);
```

In fact, it works, but it pollutes global `window` namespace and risks a clash.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var Memory = (function() {
  function Memory() {}

  Memory.prototype.evalExpr = function(expr) {
    return eval(expr);
  };

  return Memory;
})();

var mem = new Memory();
```

Then each instruction `inst` is executed using:

```
mem[inst.name] = mem.evalExpr(inst.expr);
```

This semi-works, but I have to change all the instructions to prepend all variable names with `this.`, i.e.:

```
[
  {"name": "a", "expr": "1"},
  {"name": "b", "expr": "4"},
  {"name": "c", "expr": "this.a * this.b + 100"},
  {"name": "a", "expr": "this.a - 5"}
]
```

Is there any quick way to do read operations withing an object in a way that won't require prepending `this.` to variable names? Properly modifying expressions on the fly would require building a full-fledged expression parser — in other words, it would be plain easier to just plug a relatively heavy-weight library like [jison](http://zaa.ch/jison/) into project) and try to live with that.

This is somewhat different from other "sandboxed JavaScript eval" questions, as:

1. I don't really need proper sandboxing, the code I execute is trusted enough, I just want to have all these resulting variables in one isolated space (for example, to do `JSON.stringify` easily on it later, etc).
2. This one deals with JavaScript engines in browser, not a standalone engine like node.js.

Comment: Can't you put the thing in an IIFE and then loop over the names and declare them at the top before doing the work?  Or just put all the "names" on some object instead of in the window?

Comment: I may not have understood your question right, but that seems simpler than trying to mess with the expression.

Comment: Have you considered using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) instead of `eval`? Another way could maybe be using `valueOf` instead of `expr` and making it a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safe usage of eval() on server-sent JavaScript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489874/safe-usage-of-eval-on-server-sent-javascript-code)

Comment: @Casey: In real-world problem, I don't have the complete array of instructions — they are generated dynamically, and, besides, wrapping everything in IIFE kind of defeats the purpose: I wouldn't be able to get results of evaluations after IIFE finishes and I won't be able to access it from external code as a proper JS object.

Comment: @Xufox I might be missing the point, but I don't really see how getters or `valueOf` might help here. These expressions are actually imperative instructions that are meant to be executed when it is requested, not scheduled as a lazy evaluation or something...

Comment: @GreyCat IIFEs can reach into window if you need to, or you could take my other suggestion and assigning to some object's fields instead of just assigning to global vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cornerstone of this question is not sandboxing, but how to access properties (i.e. `a`, `b`, ...) of a given object (say, `mem`) in JavaScript as local variables, i.e. without any prefixes like `this.a` or `mem.a`.

It comes out that the solution is the infamous [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) (just as `eval`, it is also frequently ["considered harmful"](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/) by some people). However, in this exact case it does the job perfectly: one can evaluate arbitrary expressions dynamically with it:

```
function VM() {
  this.mem = {};
}

VM.prototype.varSet = function(varName, expr) {
  var _t;
  with (this.mem) { _t = eval(expr) };
  this.mem[varName] = _t;
};

vm = new VM()
```

Thus, it's easy to execute instructions:

```
insts.forEach(function(inst) {
  vm.varSet(inst.name, inst.expr);
});
```

get individual results:

```
vm.mem.a // => -4
```

and get all the results together as proper plain JavaScript object, for example, to export is as a JSON string:

```
JSON.stringify(vm.mem) // => "{\"a\":-4,\"b\":4,\"c\":104}"
```