# eval not working under nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

How come eval does not work under nodejs?

```
function show(myVariable) {
    var myValue = eval(myVariable);
    console.log(myVariable + "=" + myValue);
}

var foo = "bar";
show("foo");
```

on a HTML page this returns `foo=bar` in the console log

in a nodejs controller it gives `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

This is the original code:

```
"use strict";
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

function show(myVariable) {
    var myValue = eval(myVariable);
    console.log(myVariable + "=" + myValue);
}

exports.messageSave = function(req, callback) {

    var foo = "bar";
    show("foo");

    return

    // a lot of other code below, but put return to focus on the problem

}
```

**UPDATE**

What I am trying to do here is for my `show` function to read the name of the variable that was parsed to it.

Comment: eval is bold!! Count yourself lucky! But I will refer you to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491365/1606432

Comment: `eval` does evaluate the expression in global scope, but unlike in the browser that `foo` variable is not a global in node

Comment: @Pogrindis nope, use strict made no difference.

Comment: @Bergi ahhhh!!  so as soon as you have some `exports.messageSave = function(req, callback) {` controllers, then it is no longer in the global scope and it will no longer work.   Is there another way to know the name of the variable that calls a function?

Comment: @torb I was not suggesting you to use strict! I was putting you off eval entirety! :D

Comment: @Pogrindis ok the link you sent suggested using strict :)

Comment: Hmmm if only there was another way for my function to see the name of the variable that called it.  This is what I need - would rather avoid using eval.

Comment: Oh, wait, wait, maybe I was wrong. Your `eval` is a direct call and should find all variables in scope, even the local ones. What's really weird though is that `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` - `foo` is a perfectly valid expression statement however. Can you show us the actual code you are using?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*my function to see the name of the variable that called it*". Are you looking for a stack trace? Maybe you should ask a new question and state your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) so that we might suggest an `eval`-less solution.

Comment: @Bergi sorry, I updated the question with my original code and tried to be more specific with the actual problem.  And what is a stack trace?  Is that something I could use?

Comment: Yes, *that* `show` function does definitely not have access to the scope that `foo` is defined in. It really would be much simpler to pass name and value (`show("foo", foo)`) or an object (`show({foo})`).

Comment: @torbenrudgaard A [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) can be accessed as [`new Error().stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack)

Comment: @Bergi you are right - changing my show function is probably the best way, otherwise it will be too much hackery :)   And thanks for showing me the error.stack, didnt know about that one. Please write a short answer so I can close the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `show` function does not work because it does not have access to the scope that `foo` is defined in. It would only work with global variables, which is probably what you tried in the browser.

Don't do too much trickery, and don't use `eval` for it. It really would be much simpler to pass name and value (`show("foo", foo)`) or an object (`show({foo})` - ES6 property shorthand syntax).

Comment: `show({foo})` ohhh yes!!  This short hand syntax is exactly what I need, it beats `"foo",foo`  - Thanks Bergi!!